# What does it mean for a grammar to be linear?

Tags: grammar, grammar-formalism

What is the definition of a ''linear'' grammar. For instance, there is a class of grammars called ``linear indexed grammars'' which is different from plain ''indexed grammars.'' What does ''linear'' refer to, formally speaking.